# Surface and Nativecrypto errors when trying to get current location

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, create-react-kotlin-app

I am getting the errors:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7fc080e0
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f5ec8fc00 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f5d8f0270 arg=0x0
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f5ec8fc00 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
```

when trying to get current location in kotlin android.

I tried with android 6 and 8 ,still getting error and I am not able to get current location on map, a blank map opens

Can anyone help me with what is the issue here, I am stuck with this issue from days?

This is my code to get current map location:

```
class MapActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private var service: LocationManager? = null
    private var enabled: Boolean? = null
    private var mCurrLocationMarker: Marker? = null
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var mGoogleApiClient:GoogleApiClient
    private lateinit var mLastLocation:Location

    private lateinit var mLocationRequest:LocationRequest

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {

        mLastLocation = location
        val latLng=LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude)

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        markerOptions.position(latLng)
        markerOptions.title("Current Position")
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA))
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f))

    }
    override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("sasas:","im here")

        mLocationRequest=LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.interval = 1000
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 1000
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        if (!enabled!!) {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        // Check if permission is granted or not
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this)
        }
//        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }
    override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {

    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        service = this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        enabled = service!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient()
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    }
    @Synchronized
    fun buildGoogleApiClient(){
        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build()
        mGoogleApiClient.connect()
    }

    }
```

What is wrong with the code above or why am I getting those errors and why a blank map is shown instead of showing current location?

Comment: I doubt errors with `Surface` and `NativeCrypto` are related to location. Did you ask for the necessary permissions? Post the code to request the location.

Comment: @nikis I have updated my question with the code.Please check.

Comment: @nikis Also  I have given permissions in my mainfest file such as:        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I solved it,it was my mistake,I was also using old stuff like fusedlocation api.I updated my code and it works now. :-) no issues